# How does the -name switch to GNU find work when targeting a directory and its contents?

Tags: find

I have a folder full of source files for an application, the project uses git for version control and so there is a `.git` directory:

```
├── composer.json
├── .git
│   ├── branches
│   ├── config
│   ├── info
│   ├── logs
│   ├── objects
│   ├── packed-refs
│   └── refs
├── .gitignore
├── Gruntfile.js
├── less
│   ├── framework
│   ├── index.less
│   └── view_specific.less
├── package.json
[...]
```

I regularly need to do something with all the source files whilst ignoring  the version control files, i.e. the `.git` directory and everything under it.
I normally use the `-not -path` option to `find` to exclude a directory, e.g.

```
find . -not -path "*git*"
```

the problem with this is that it is too broad, e.g. it will exclude the `.gitignore` file, and any other files that have *git* in them, e.g. *agitate*, *fugitive* etc.
I discovered `find` with the `-name` and `-prune` switch does seem to target the `.git` directory and its contents:

```
% find . -name ".git" -prune -o -print | grep git
./.gitignore
```

but I don't understand  how `-name` is matching the filenames.
From `man find`

> ```
>    -name pattern
>       Base  of  file  name (the path with the leading directories removed) matches shell pattern pattern.
> ```

To me this implies, `-name` only matches when the pattern matches the last segment in a filename, e.g. `-name foo` would match `/dir1/dir2/foo` but **not**  `/dir1/dir2/foo/dir3/dir4/some_file`
to me the whole point of `-path` was for matching patterns like `foo` to files with pathnames like `/dir1/dir2/foo/dir3/dir4/some_file`.
It seems `-name` can match any segment in the filepath - not just the last segment - as long as its a complete match to the segment within the slashes?
Otherwise how does `-name` match file names?

Comment: The behavior you are observing is due to `-prune`, not `-name` (what do you think `-prune` is doing otherwise?). `-name` is behaving exactly as you expect it to. Also `-path` matches the whole path, not just any one directory in it.

Comment: @Patrick to me it seems that `name` is responsible, because if I use `find . -path ".git" -prune -o -print`  the `.git` directories and all the files underneath are not pruned, they are matched and printed, if I simply swap the `-path` to `-name` the `.git` VCS files do get pruned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore the `.git` directories and everything underneath them you need a construct like this

```
find . \( -name '.git' -prune \) -o \( -print {or whatever else you want to do} \)
```

This tells `find` that when it finds a file or directory called `.git` it's to *prune* its tree and not descend any further down that path. Everything else can be matched - and processed - within the other half of the *or* condition construct.

<sub>(The backslashes on the brackets stop them being processed by the shell, and for this simplistic example are technically un-necessary. I've left them in to make it explicitly obvious how the *and* and *or* constructs bind.)</sub>

Now, consider your concern with a folder called `foo`:

> e.g. `-name foo` would match `/dir1/dir2/foo` but not `/dir1/dir2/foo/dir3/dir4/some_file`

You are correct, but I think you've missed the corollary. At some point `find` will reach `/dir1/dir2/foo`. The `-name foo` will match and so the `-prune` will be invoked. `find` cannot reach below `foo` without first seeing `foo` itself.

Consequently `/dir1/dir2/foo/dir3/dir4/some_file` can never be reached.

The initial result from inspection is that somehow `-name foo` matches `/dir1/dir2/foo/dir3/dir4/some_file`, but in reality it matched on `/dir1/dir2/foo` and abandoned any further inspection of that tree.

In contrast to `-name foo`, which matches `foo` only as the last component of a path, `-path foo` will match only if `foo` is a complete path. (`find * -path foo` might match a `foo` at the top level, but `find . -path foo` could never match `./foo`.)

Comment: that explains perfectly, I didn't realise that `-prune` started at the parent directory, descended incrementally, then cut the entire subtree once it matched a filename, hence the subdirectories not even  considered. really  well written/explained answer, thanks!

Comment: @the_velour_fog it doesn't. `-prune` stops `find` descending a tree at the point that it's matched. The `-name` does the matching.

Comment: ok, my summary/paraphrasing of it probably  didn't make sense, but yes, that's essentially  how I understood your answer

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of `-name` is correct. It only matches the file name; the path leading to the file (the chain of containing directories) is irrelevant.

What you're missing is the effect of `-prune`. Contrast

```
find . -name ".git" -o -print
```

which means “if it's called `.git`, then do nothing, else print the path and recurse into it if it's a directory” with

```
find . -name ".git" -prune -o -print
```

which means “if it's called `.git`, then *do not recurse into it*, else print the path and recurse into it if it's a directory”.

Comment: thanks Gilles, so I am right to assume `find` will always perform the tests on the upper level, parent directories, before it descends into the folder to perform tests on child folders. In other words, you will never get a scenario where `find` checks a child folder first, prints, then later on, checks and prunes a parent/ancestor of the sub-directory.

Comment: @the_velour_fog Yes. Actually you can make `find` perform the tests and actions on a directory after traversing its children with the `-depth` global option. This option is incompatible with `-prune`.

Comment: ah! thats what `-depth` does, `man find` states the same thing, but I couldn't work it out from the man page.